# Collapsing stick header with a ViewPager with a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a layout similar to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar/master/graphics/notboringab.gif).

The catch is that the content needs to be a view pager (that contains scrollable content).

My current plan is to implement this with one of the following

1. Make the main view a linear layout with the top section holding the header taking up fixed space (the viewpager fills whatever is left). Listen for touch events on the linear layout to expand or shrink the header, once the header has reached the minimum size, propagate the scroll events through to the viewpager (how?).
2. Same as 1., but wrapped in a ScrollView
3. Same as 1., but listen for scrolling in the viewpager and propagate that back up the view hierarchy (onScroll Listeners of some kind).
4. Same as 3, but wrapped in a ScrollView

I have a better idea on how to implement 3/4, but it seems like it introduces a lot of coupling, and "feels gross". I have less of an idea on how to do 1/2, but it feels (slightly) less gross. In either case, using the LinearLayout, I would have to override onTouch, rather than onScroll. Not sure which of those is preferable.

Ideally I would like to find a more elegant solution (possibly from Android L), but I welcome insights/pros/cons to my proposed solutions as well.